# Math Symbol From Mysql To HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not able to bring symbols "square root" and "theta" from mysql to html

Comment: Is it possible that you're using two different encodings? The simplest way is to use the same encoding for querying the database, processing the data (strings) and outputting.

Comment: Either make sure the character encodings match in your database and HTML charset, or use the `&radic;` and `&theta;` entities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys....yes i am using the same encoding but i am having very huge data where these symbols occurs many times...so i cant hard code it...right??please reply

Answer (score 3):

HTML will not recognize those symbols unless they are converted to HTML Entities - notation like `&#8730;` for the square root sign. You can convert to them from MySQL using PHPs [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

W3C HTML 5 entity reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Overview of useful HTML entities: http://htmlentities.net/html/entities/

Comment: Shouldn't a good browser be able to display these symbols if they're properly encoded (using Unicode)? **Test:** √

Comment: Yes, a good browser SHOULD display most of those symbols - but I have seen plenty of browsers doing retarded things - so he should be converting them to entities to at least be in standards compliance. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp for more information. Also, if they aren't encoded in UTF-8, htmlentities() will handle many encoding types.

Comment: +1 I want to add that you **should not** store these entities in the database itself. The DB stores the data and not any representation format for a browser. @Jack That table should be fine but you shouldn't use this site as a reference (see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)).

Comment: @ComFreek lol yeah I know about W3Fools, W3C is just the #1 Google site for HTML entities and it is just a table. +1 for that :-)